# ListView inside two LinearLayout and scrolling issue

Tags: android, listview, scroll, android-linearlayout

I have this structure

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/1">

   <LinearLayout
   android:id="@+id/2" />

   <LinearLayout
   android:id="@+id/3">
      <ListView
      android:id="@android:id/list" />
   </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And I populate the `ListView` with some data. Well my problem is that the `ListView` becomes scrollable (while the `LinearLayout` number 1 fits the screen without scrolling), but what I want is this `View` to become full height and that the `LinearLayout` with `id=1` becomes scrollable.

Inside `ListView` number 2 I have some `TextView`s, etc.

Comment: did you found solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

ListView's are scrollable by default if when the content is more than its display area.

However, LinearLayout would need to have a ScrollView in order to scroll.

Red Alert - You cannot use ScrollView and ListView together. You will end up seeing un-expected.

Alternate Solution: Prioritize what is more important to you, if scrolling the entire screen then add a ScrollView (provided your ListView items are static) else I will to wait to hear a good solution on this one. :)

Comment: I have a "card" with a profile basic information and then a list of items related to this profile. If the list becomes very big, to have a small scrollable `LinearLayout` will become uncomfortable. Let's see if I find a solution.

Comment: As visible from your layout, the ListView lies to the bottom (so the layout may not scroll beyond it) and as you said its items can grow larger, so you should go with ListView till you get a solution. Do let me know as well so that even I can use it. :)

Comment: I'll do so! I'm thinking, I could even want to add another "card" with some information under the `ListView`, but by now it would make the `ListView` even smaller...

Comment: Adding a new card will make your layout more complex. Why dont you use tabs to represent cards? how many cards do you have at a time? or can you post an image as to what you want the layout to look like?

Comment: I didn't think of that approach, and could be a good solution! Btw I could do it with a `ScrollView` that encapsulates everything and with a method that calculates the height for the ListView and forces it through `listView.setLayoutParams()`. I know that I'm not supposed to use `ScrollView` and `ListView`, thus I'm changing it.

Comment: Hmm this method might be useful (will have to see for all possible odds though). Let know how it goes coz ScrollView vs ListView is a tough battle always. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Add ScrollView for ListView.
ScrollView will work for only one child view, so you have to add like this

LinearLayout

LinearLayout
LinearLayout

ScrollView

ListView...../ListView

/ScrollView

/LinearLayout